# Is TimeSeriesSplit necessary if I set shuffle to False in train_test_split?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, regression, train-test-split

Currently, I am using a regression model on a time-series. To assign train and test data, I generally use train_test_split from sklearn and it looks like this:

`X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, Y_Test = train_test_split(X.to_numpy(), Y.to_numpy(), test_size=.30, shuffle=False)`

Doing this, each variable is assigned an array with the relevant data. However, since it is time-series data, I would like the training set to only use values that come before the test values. I assumed setting shuffle to False did this, and it appears that way when I just look at the variables, but surely this TimeSeriesSplit model wouldn't be created if this was case, right?

When I try to implement this, the documentation for TimeSeriesSplit is **extremely** confusing for a beginner. It seems to only take in a vaguely defined "n*splits" parameter, but it doesn't have any other instructions on how I can just simply assign x*train, xtest, ytrain, and ytest. So is it even necessary? Does it do anything that isn't done by setting shuffle to False?

The furthest I can get, even after exhausting all resources is:
`time_series_split = TimeSeriesSplit()`

The dataset is structured as follows:

| date | this month's value | next_month's returns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/22 | 30 | -5 |
| 02/22 | 10 | 5 |
| 03/22 | 50 | -10 |
| 04/22 | 5 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Using `TimeSeriesSplit()` usually means cross-validation. If you just need to separate the test set, `train_test_split(shuffle=False)` is sufficient.
However, if you happen to need several subsets without future data leakage, `TimeSeriesSplit()` is able to simplify things a lot, i.e.:

```
time_series_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=4)
gs = GridSearchCV(cv=time_series_split, ... # add parameters as needed)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```